# UWP App closing as soon as it opens (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) - error

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, uwp-xaml

We have a sideload AppXBundle where we are experiencing the app crashing right after it shows the splash screen.

We install the certificate from our store association, double click on the appxbundle - App Installer prompt appears, and we click install. As mentioned, the splash screen shows, and then within a few seconds the app closes.

Here is the error message from the Event Viewer:

```
Faulting application name: TestApp.exe, version: 1.1.11.0, time stamp: 0x5f0453e7
Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.18362.815, time stamp: 0x9fa806f2
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x0000000000713530
Faulting process id: 0x1b84
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6544d6b4a7c36
Faulting application path: C:\Program 
Files\WindowsApps\TestApp_1.0.31.0_x64__e3skdg3cf6xk8\TestApp.UWP.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
Report Id: 2eda3b62-5ac6-46cd-89b2-b251d05dea05
Faulting package full name: TestApp_1.0.31.0_x64__e3skdg3cf6xk8
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

We have done quite a bit of research on the Windows.UI.XAML dll issue - I have uninstalled it with powershell, and reinstalled it. I tried updating it. Nothing seems to do the trick.

We have tried it with every compile version I can for the device (x64,x86,ARM,ARM64)

The target device is a Surface GO, but we have expereinced the app crashing on x64 desktops with Windows version 17143+.

We have this issue only on specific computers. 1909(build 18363.836) <- windows version where the app works.

If you need more information, please let us know.

Comment: Hello, is the `specific computers` you are referring to the device with system version 17134? According to the error message, usually, the error is related to your UI, such as using a control or property that is not supported by the current system version, or the layout is abnormal. You mentioned in the description that you upgraded the system of the device. In the latest version (2004), will the application still crash? Based on the tags of the question, are you using `Xamarin.Forms` to develop UWP applications?

Comment: Yes we used Xamarin.Forms to develop this application.

We set the min version for the UWP to v.1803(build 17134)

the devices that it works on runs: v. 1909(build 18363.836)[I see now it was a mistake to say the newest version, will fix the post.]
not working: v.1903 (build 18362.836)

^Maybe it looks like there is obviously there problem, but I have matched the versions and builds previously, and still no luck.

Comment: Hello, from your test results, you may have used the API that was fixed by the high version (1909), which caused it to fail to run on the low version (1803). It is not known what API is causing this problem. Can you provide a minimum reproducible demo for us to test? (Does not contain private information).

Comment: I'm seeing something similar in my app... what was the fix?